# Arima forecast giving straight line

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

[image: Arima Model with p=1 q=1 d=1.]

Why is it giving me a straight line whereas we can see that there is a pattern? Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have build this model in python using statsmodel library.

I want the forecast for the year 2017. But it is coming a straight line. I want to know why there are no fluctuations? The data given was weekly data and I applied ARIMA model with order (1,1,1). With d=1, the series was becoming stationary.

Comment: We need more information. What orders of ARIMA were used?

Comment: Try Seasonal ARIMA instead if your time series is seasonal

Comment: We do need more info. - bear in mind also that you're forecasting the *mean*, which won't be wiggly like the series itself.

Comment: Order was p=1, q=1, d=1.

Comment: Given data was weekly data and forecast is for the next year.

Comment: I don't think your selected software is up to this problem as there appears to be an annual seasonality . I suggest  a hybrid model incorporating both ARIMA structure and possibly some deterministic structure. please post your data

Answer (score 2):

You have considered orders(1,1,1) which explains stationary data.
You also need to consider seasonal factor to get desired output.

order = c(1,1,1), seasonal = c(1,1,1)